# How to get difference between two rows for a columns field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| MRLNum | CreatedOn | ReviseCode | RequiredQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 0 | 100 |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 1 | 30 |

This will list values by rowInt. How can get get the difference of Value between two rows with the result like this:

| MRLNum | CreatedOn | ReviseCode | RequiredQty | ReviseCodePrvDiff | RequiredQtyPrvDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 0 | 100 | NA | NA |
| SAN-000027-001 | 2/28/2023 | 1 | 30 | 0 | 100 |

The table is in SQL 2017 (Miscrosoft)

Comment: Use [`lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), as shown in the most upvoted answer in the duplicate link for example.

Comment: mention link not resolved the problem please look into again

Comment: please, read the link until it resolves the problem - the LAG/LEAD functions were designed for these types of tasks.

Comment: You need a way to sort the rows for LAG/LEAD by some column(s) to work. In your example, what should one sort on ? ReviseCode?